# Make plant experience 2 growing seasons per year by moving it across equator semiyearly

Tags: botany, growth

If I take a typical plant (such as e.g. a rosemary plant or an avocado sapling) across the equator from Florida to Brazil and back every year, so that the plant experiences Spring in both places, will the plant experience two growing seasons? Or is there some genetic wiring in the plant to prevent this?

Comment: Is this a theoretical question? Because if you live in Florida, you would probably know that you can have already two growing seasons there.

Comment: Oh, can you elaborate on that? I don't live in Florida, so the question is theoretical in that regard--but the question is a practical one.

Comment: Maybe a real practical question would be better to post then. For theoretical questions you can better go to e.g., stack exchange biology

Comment: @benn I'm not sure what you mean. Are you suggesting the question would be more practical if I put in the actual state I lived in? That seems unrelated to what I'm interested in.

Comment: I mean, please ask what you really want to do, instead of describing a hypothetical situation (in places where you don't live). Just ask, I have this plant, I live here and there, how can I do this or that with it? You'll probably get a better answer than for this question, don't you think?

Comment: Thank you for the pointers @benn. The question I've asked is the one I'd like to have answered though

Comment: You know it's illegal to shuffle live plants around as described, right? Generally, afaik, plants can't tell time and perennials take the cue from the environment, so yes, you would get two growing seasons ala hothouse tomatoes. Some plants might need more time than others, so how well the plant would actually do depends on many specifics. For example, the stems might be to thin to support the fruit or flowers triggered by the seasonal sun because they didn't have enough time to vegetate and bulk up in the spring wind.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is an hypothetical question, while this community wants actual problems (see tour). Or it would be better placed on stack exchange biology, since it is theoretical and has nothing to do with real gardening.

Comment: Hi @benn, just to repeat, this is not a theoretical question. This is a practical question that I'm concerned with. I've replaced the state that I'm in just to stay as anonymous as possible on the internet.

Comment: @dandavis Thank you for the message! I was not aware of legality issues surrounding this.

Comment: @dandavis: Plants take cues from the environment, so they might need a certain amount of cold, or other cues, before breaking dormancy.  This is something that you might expect to evolve in order to avoid the effects of an early cold snap in the fall.  In fact, many plants do require a certain number of "chill hours".  See e.g. https://ucanr.edu/blogs/blogcore/postdetail.cfm?postnum=16468

Comment: I think you'll find there's no "typical" plant.

Comment: @Armand interesting, could you elaborate?